# Server/Client Connection

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

Concerning Server/Client connection :
 .Net socket server CAN communicate with .Net socket Client such as:
the desktop application developed in VS.net (Server listening in .net Web sockets)

```
enter code here

TcpListener Server= new TcpListener("127.0.0.1", 8000);

. . .

Server.Start()
```

Works perfect and listens to connections coming from clients

Unity3d  Server CAN communicate perfectly with Unity Client as well.

but a desktop application using  Websockets (Such in the upper example) doesn't listen/communicate with connections coming from Unity3d client such:

```
enter code here

client = new NetworkClient();
client.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnClientConnect);
client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8000);
```

any suggestions?